Must you "deactivate" homebrew to run conda?
Based on this post. I know the post says that it's a good idea to deactivate conda before running brew, but what about the opposite? I was wondering if there is anything you need to do to customize the conda command so that it doesn't conflict with brew.
So far, I haven't ever came across "deactivating" brew. Both commands (brew and conda) seem to be working; I am just wondering if it is better practice to customize the conda command as well. Appreciate your insights

Never worked with Conda, but AFIK this sets up an evironment to run various Python version. It makes sense to say "deactivate Conda", which I would understand that you run the Python version which comes with your Mac. OTOH, Homebrew does not "set up" anything, so I don't know what it would mean to "deactive" it. In this way, your question doesn't sound meaningful to me.

When they say "deactivate Conda", I think they mean "deactivate any Conda virtual environment that might be active", so that when brew tries to run Python, it's running its own Python, not whatever you have installed in the virtual environment. brew, on the other hand, doesn't create virtual environments at all, so there's nothing to deactivate when running Conda.
